# CKEditor with CKFinder - disable FileBrowser, Keep Upload functionality

Tags: browser, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am using CKFinder integrated in CKEditor.
I want to keep the Upload feature active, but scrap the Browse Server option as I don't want users doing this.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shorthand is after you setup the CKFinder integration with CKEditor, override the URLs to the FileBrowser:

```
//Prevent the fileBrowser button and option
$CKEditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl']='';
$CKEditor->config['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl']='';
$CKEditor->config['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl']='';
```